# Facebook Comments CreatedTime is Wrong

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-comments

I use this url in browser and all data returned are correct

> https://graph.facebook.com/399455050251075/comments

but when use Facebook SDK for android the

> "created_time": 1444239249

but in browser

> "created_time": "2015-10-07T17:34:09+0000"

and they are not same as they have to be 
I use Facebook SDK version "3.19.0"

### I don't want to upgrade SDK now if it can be resolves without updating

the is raw response from Response Object in Facebook SDK

```
{
    Response: responseCode: 200,
    graphObject: GraphObject{
        graphObjectClass=GraphObject,
        state={
            "data": [{
                "created_time": 1444239249,
                "from": {
                    "name": "Mahmoud El-Naggar",
                    "id": "520891598050037"
                },
                "message": "some exciting missions being launched soon i hear!!",
                "can_remove": true,
                "like_count": 0,
                "user_likes": false,
                "id": "399455050251075_412289715634275"
            },
            {
                "created_time": 1443600305,
                "from": {
                    "name": "Spotter Man",
                    "id": "448133032016057"
                },
                "message": "fantastic",
                "can_remove": false,
                "like_count": 1,
                "user_likes": false,
                "id": "399455050251075_410851479111432"
            },
            {
                "created_time": 1443543478,
                "from": {
                    "name": "Spotter Man",
                    "id": "448133032016057"
                },
                "message": "Great",
                "can_remove": false,
                "like_count": 1,
                "user_likes": false,
                "id": "399455050251075_410732165790030"
            },
            {
                "created_time": 1440332320,
                "from": {
                    "name": "Subul Tanveer",
                    "id": "10206076595886469"
                },
                "message": "Very well deserved you guys!",
                "can_remove": false,
                "like_count": 1,
                "user_likes": false,
                "id": "399455050251075_399466336916613"
            }],
            "paging": {
                "cursors": {
                    "before": "NgZDZD",
                    "after": "MwZDZD"
                }
            }
        }
    },
    error: null,
    isFromCache: false
}
```

you can see the difference between this result and the one on browser

Comment: I would guess 2 different version of the API is used. Specify a version of the API and I'm guessing you will get the same result

Comment: how I can specify api version in facebook sdk

Comment: https://graph.facebook.com/v2.0/399455050251075/comments to call v2.0 for example. Also make sure that you use the same access token in both cases

Comment: @WizKid browser gives me correct data , the problem in facebook sdk , when it try to convert created_date to milliseconds

Comment: You are sure that the SDK does that?

Comment: yes , I put breakpoints everywhere to get json response, see me edit on my question

Comment: unix timestamp 1444239249 is exactly the same as 2015-10-07T17:34:09+0000 (semantically, at least)